# Building go plugins with gazelle

Tags: go, plugins, bazel, bazel-gazelle

I'm building a project written in go with the bazel build system and its `gazelle` extension to automatically generate `BUILD` files.

The project's file tree is similar to this:

```
project-root/
... cmd/
... ... cmd1/
... ... cmd2/
... internal/
... ... internalPackage1/
... ... internalPackage2/
... plugins/
... ... plugin1/
... ... plugin2/
... ... pluginCategory/
... ... ... plugin3/
... ... ... plugin4/
... go.mod
```

The commands and the internal packages are built correctly, but when it comes to building the plugins, I've read that I need to compile them using `go build -buildmode=plugin`.
If I were to manually write the `BUILD` files, I could add to the `go_binary` rule the `linkmode = "plugin"` argument.

Now, for my questions:

- Is there any configuration or parameters I can pass to `gazelle` in order to add this argument to all `BUILD` files generated under a specific directory (`plugin/`) and preferably its sub-directories (to support the plugin categories as shown above)?
- If not, is there a tool other than `gazelle` to generate bazel `BUILD` files that supports plugins like that?
- What is the industry's best practice on building go plugins with bazel?

Thank you in advance.